# Firestore security rules - allow only users in chat to read document

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am building an app that has chat functionality and need some help writing my firestore rules.

Each chat looks like this in Firestore

```
/chats/{documentId}

messages (collection)

createdAt: Timestamp
lastChat: String
lastMessageSent: Timestamp
users: ["user1234", "user4321"]
```

The `documentId` in this case would be `user1234.user4321`

How can I write my firestore rules so that only `user1234` and `user4321` can read and update this document and its subcollection?

Comment: It should be fairly simple to test whether the UID exists in the `users` array. Did you try anything yet?

Comment: Hi @Kevin Miller, as mentioned by Frank, do you have any Firestore Security Rules to begin with? You may refer to this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) to start building your Firestore Security Rules.